# Angular Directive with Options, Callbacks like jQuery Widgets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm creating a custom control. I'm thinking of using Angular Directives.

But I see that directives require you to initialize your widget with html for example:

```
<mywidget></mywidget>
```

And in order to pass variables you also do this in html:

```
<mywidget title="my widget"></mywidget>
```

But I don't want this. I want to the initialization of my object programatically. Think jQuery widgets:

```
$('#container').mywidget({

    title: 'my widget',
    somecallback: function(event, ui){
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Basically, I'd like to set options and set callbacks programatically. Is this available using angular directives or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can not only pass just a string to a directive, but any kind of object or functions that are "programmatically" defined in a controller. For instance:

Your HTML:

```
<mywidget callback="someFunction()"></mywidget>
```

Your directive:

```
directive('mywidget', function() {
  return {
    scope: { callback: '&' }
  };
});
```

Your upper controller:

```
$scope.someFunction = function() {
  // programatically do something
}
```

Comment: yes but what if I wanted to pass in something into my user control like big array or something? (for example, let's say I got an array from the server)

Comment: As I said, you can pass anything, whatever how big it is. The other answer gives you more info about the different structures you can pass, and I'd also recommend reading the official doc for directives

Answer (score 0):

Angular is declarative not imperative by nature which means you don't get to do that in an easy way and is for a good reason(separation of concerns) 
making your directives clearly bound to your html helps readbility, maintenability and testability, now, you still get to configure your directive using the different binding types in your directives scope definition you can do this inside your directive

```
scope:{
   configs:'='
}
```

which will create 2 way data binding with the config object which you can use to configure your directive and comunicate with the config object owner, or you can do

```
scope:{
   configs:'&'
}
```

and then on your direcitves controller or link function do

```
scope.configs=scope.configs();
```

to get the object and then you can use it to configure, notice this doesn't create a 2way binding wit the object but it returns and object representation instead some thing similar goes to callback functions or events callback using the 2 way biding  operator '='(not recommended but possible) or you can set it using the evaluation operation '&'

```
  scope:{
      onClick:'&'
  }
```

and then on your controller/link function do

```
 scope.onClick=scope.onClick();
```

and use it as

scope.onClick(params)

then when you declare your directive you do

more on this you can find here

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile